# Highlighting one edittext when clicked and make the highlight lost when clicked on another edittext

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext, highlighting

Hi I created edittexts dynamically in the adapter class and disabled soft keypad as I have my own custom keypad. But the problem is the textfield is not getting highlighted when it is clicked and even cursor is also not visible. So, I created an xml file as a 9-patch and placed it in drawable folder to change atleast the background of the edittext when it is clicked. So that it would be clear  that the particular edittext is clicked. But it is showing the constant color(Thick green) always and in turn making the borders invisible and getting that color fixed where ever I clicked. Even the cursor is getting fixed some places. Below is the code and screen shot of the app for the clear idea. Please advice how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
public class TextAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {



    Context mContext;
    int count=81;
    int k=0;
    static EditText current;



    public TextAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final EditText editText;

        if (convertView == null) {      


            editText = new EditText(mContext);
            editText.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(54, 53));
            editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittextshape);
            editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            editText.setFocusable(false);

            editText.setId(k);
            k++;

            editText.setFilters( new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1)});


            editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    current = (EditText) v;
                    current.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.shape1);  //here I set the background color
                    current.requestFocus();

                }

            });



            editText.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            editText = (EditText) convertView;
        }

        editText.setText("");

        return editText;
    }

    public static EditText getCurrentEditText() throws Exception
    {

        System.out.println("In getCurrent method "+current);
        return current;

    }


}
```

[image]